# Index error in binary search in an infinite sorted array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, binary-search, index-error

The program gives `IndexError: list index out of range` in **binary search** in the infinite sorted array when the element does not exist or is too large

```
def binarySearch(l,ele,low=0,high=None):
    if(high==None):
        high=len(l)-1
    if(low>high):
        return -1
    mid= int((low+high)/2)
    pEle = l[mid]
    if(pEle==ele):
            return mid 
    elif(pEle>ele):
        return binarySearch(l,ele,low,mid-1)
    else:
        return binarySearch(l,ele,mid+1,high)
# This is a function that searches elements in an infinite sorted array
# l=array;ele=element
def binarySearchInfiniteSortedArray(l,ele):
    low,high=0,1
    while(True):
        pEle = l[high]
        if(pEle==ele):
            return high
        elif(pEle>ele or pEle==l[-1]):
            break
        else:
            low,high = high+1,high*2
    return binarySearch(l,ele,low,high)
```

Comment: You may try with arithematic mean to get into the range however the geometric mean will get you to the answer faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value of `high` is getting doubled in each loop and when the value of `high` becomes greater than or equal to the length of list it gives `IndexError: list index out of range`

```
def binarySearchInfiniteSortedArray(l,ele):
    low,high=0,1
    while(True):
        try:
            pEle = l[high]
        except:
            high = int((high**0.5)*(low**0.5))
            continue
        if(pEle==ele):
            return high
        elif(pEle>ele or pEle==l[-1]):
            break
        else:
            low,high = high+1,high*2
    return binarySearch(l,ele,low,high)
```

Once the error is there we can do a try except and get the Geometrical mean of `high` and `low` unless u are inside the range again or get the answer. Hope my points are clear.